# Conditional MySQL order by two (equally important) columns

Tags: mysql, sorting, conditional-statements

I have a list of products with lots of columns but the 3 most important for my problem are these (with some random data):

```
|--------------------------------------|
| title     | category_id | date       |
| ----------|-------------|------------|
|  Product1 |           1 | 2012-04-18 |
|  Product2 |           1 | 0000-00-00 |
|  Product3 |          17 | 0000-00-00 |
|  Product4 |          17 | 2012-04-10 |
|  Product5 |          17 | 2012-04-20 |
|  Product6 |           1 | 0000-00-00 |
|  Product7 |           2 | 2012-04-20 |
|  Product8 |           2 | 0000-00-00 |
|  Product9 |          17 | 2012-04-16 |
| Product10 |          22 | 2011-11-26 |
| Product11 |          22 | 2011-12-25 |
| Product12 |          30 | 2012-04-01 |
| Product13 |           2 | 2011-12-31 |
| Product14 |          30 | 2010-05-06 |
|--------------------------------------|
```

The products with the same `category_id` should be listed one after another (at this point this could be even solved by "ORDER BY category_id"), BUT I have to take care about the `date` column as well: the `category_id` and the products within the categories have to be sorted by `date` descending (the `category_id` with the newest product on top and so on), so ideally the resultset should be something like this (added line breaks between category "groups" just to be more transparent):

```
|--------------------------------------|
| title     | category_id | date       |
| ----------|-------------|------------|
|  Product5 |          17 | 2012-04-20 |
|  Product9 |          17 | 2012-04-16 |
|  Product4 |          17 | 2012-04-10 |
|  Product3 |          17 | 0000-00-00 |

|  Product7 |           2 | 2012-04-20 |
| Product13 |           2 | 2011-12-31 |
|  Product8 |           2 | 0000-00-00 |

|  Product1 |           1 | 2012-04-18 |
|  Product2 |           1 | 0000-00-00 |
|  Product6 |           1 | 0000-00-00 |

| Product12 |          30 | 2012-04-01 |
| Product14 |          30 | 2010-05-06 |

| Product11 |          22 | 2011-12-25 |
| Product10 |          22 | 2011-11-26 |
|--------------------------------------|
```

Would it be possible to get this resultset with only one query and what would be a working solution?

Thanks in advance,
marcell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find latest date for each category in a subquery, join this subquery to your table and order by 3 fields:

```
SELECT p.* FROM products p
JOIN
( SELECT category_id, MAX(date) as category_date FROM products
  GROUP BY category_id ) pg
ON p.category_id = pg.category_id
ORDER BY pg.category_date DESC, p.category_id, p.date DESC
```

Comment: I like the approach but what do you think, how slow/fast would be this with a resultset of let's say 10000 products?

Comment: Since its a custom order it's not possible to do it entirely using indexes without changing table schema, so you will see filesort in the explain. You can use index on (category_id,date) for the subquery, but not for the order by. But as long as the temporary table fits in memory it should be fast. How fast exactly depends obviously on your hardware and size of your columns.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, it worked better than the other one, however just for the record I'd say I had to add an additional `order by max_date desc` into the subquery to achieve the exact desired sort as well as a `where category_id in (...)` to gain some speed.

Answer (score 0):

So you first want to sort by the date which is the max date within the group of products with the same id, then you want to sort the dates within the groups.

Use this:

```
SELECT title, category_id, date
FROM table_name t
ORDER BY
    (SELECT Max(Date)
     FROM table_name
     WHERE title = t.title
     GROUP BY category_id) DESC,
    date DESC
```

Instead of `title` you can use the `product_id` in the inner sql query.

Comment: The idea may be right, but you can't use subquery in order like that.