# Order by 2 columns in MySQL and set importance level

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to sort my data by two of my database column results.

Currently a sample of my data looks as follows:

```
name   type   state
paul   1      expired
john   3      expired
greg   1      active
jane   3      expired
joan   3      active
judy   2      expired
```

I'd like to display my data by active first and then by type as follows:

```
name   type   state
greg   1      active
paul   1      expired

joan   3      active
jane   3      expired
john   3      expired

judy   2      expired
```

I've tried a few combinations of:

```
ORDER BY type desc, state desc
```

Which allows me to sort by type, but doesn't allow me to put all the active ones first. I've also ordered by state and then type, but that puts all the active ones at the top and then sorts by type underneath that.

Any suggestions would be welcome!

I've looked at these two posts while trying to find my answer put I haven't had any luck so far.

[ORDER BY an equal value in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405609/order-by-an-equal-value-in-mysql)

[Conditional MySQL order by two (equally important) columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311179/conditional-mysql-order-by-two-equally-important-columns)

----EDIT----

If I order by

```
ORDER BY state, type
```

I get the following results:

```
name   type   state
greg   1      active
joan   3      active
paul   1      expired
john   3      expired
jane   3      expired
judy   2      expired
```

----EDIT 2----

If I order by

```
ORDER BY type, state
```

I get the following results with expired in the middle, where I'd like to be able to put an emphasis on displaying the active records first, as this is just a small sample of a much larger data set:

```
name   type   state
greg   1      active
paul   1      expired
judy   2      expired
joan   3      active
john   3      expired
jane   3      expired
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: paste the result of `ORDER BY type, state`

Comment: The edit 2 result is same as that of your expected result, what else do you need in this, kindly specify

Comment: Hi Sasha, I needed Judy to appear last in the list as type 2 doesn't have any active states. I didn't realise I could specify using order by field, so I'm going to give that a go now as it should work for what I need. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Have updated my query, kindly check

Comment: Great thanks - have upvoted as I hadn't thought to use the Having command :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your `ORDER BY` statement, state "active" is before "expired" in the alphabetical order, so you need to order by ASCENDANT

Edit: and for having the exact output you asked, you can use `ORDER BY FIELD(fieldname, '1st val', '2nd val')` which allows you to customize the exact order :

```
ORDER BY FIELD(`type`, 1, 3, 2), FIELD(`type`, "active", "expired");
```

Comment: yeah, that's really great when you have a large number of id and you want query all table datas in a specific order. For PHP, you can do this : `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM sometable ORDER BY FIELD(id, '.implode(',', $array_right_order).')';`

Answer (score 1):

Try this::

```
Select 
* 
from 
myTable
GROUP BY state, type HAVING STATE='active'
    ORDER BY `TYPE`, `state`
```

Comment: Unfortunately that sorts all the active ones and then all the expired ones and then sorts by type together. So it displays as:active, active, active and then expired, expired, expired rather than grouping by type but with active ones first in the list if that makes sense

Comment: Why dont you provide with the sqlfiddle